# Copy Entire Doctype tag from input document using XSLT 2.0

Tags: html, xml, xslt, doctype

I have tried a few things, but with no success. I have an input document with declared file entities. I need to copy it exactly as is to output document. This is what it looks like (# is redacted symbol here):

```
<!DOCTYPE ##### PUBLIC "-##//EN"
"###.dtd" [
<!ENTITY Chap##-## SYSTEM "###.xml">
<!ENTITY Chap##-### SYSTEM "####.xml">
<!ENTITY Chap##-#### SYSTEM "#####.xml">
```

As it stands now, I use an identity template and a match ='/' to save the document to a variable and then use specific template matches to match all other XML elements and output them as specific HTML elements. The only thing that doesn't work is keeping that doctype statement in tact.

Comment: In the Java world you can try to plug in http://andrewjwelch.com/lexev/ into your tool chain so that the DOCTYPE is preprocessed into XML markup visible to your XSLT where you can then write templates to transform or output is as needed, perhaps also using Saxon specific extensions like http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/extensions/instructions/doctype.html

Answer (score 1):

One trick with XSLT 2.0 (or higher) would be use the function [`unparsed-text()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#function-unparsed-text) to read the source document as a string, and then apply a regex or use other string functions to select the DTD section from the top of the file to include in your output using [`xsl:value-of`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-value-of) with `disable-output-escaping="yes"`

For example, using [`replace()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-replace) with a regex pattern and a capture group:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml"  indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" 
                      select="replace(
                                unparsed-text(base-uri()), 
                                '.*?(\n?&lt;!DOCTYPE\s.*\]>)\n?&lt;.*', 
                                '$1', 
                                's')"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Mads Hansen. I had been trying something like this for two days, and couldn't get it to cooperate. I'm up and moving again. I appreciate it!

Comment: Mads Hansen, it turns out this also copies all of the text in the document, before the transformation is done on the rest of the elements. Any tips on outputting *just* the entity list with this statement?

Comment: You could add an empty template matching on `/text()/following-sibling::*`, `/*/preceding-sibling::text()`, or more generically for whitespace-only text nodes `text()[not(normalize-space())]` in order to exclude them from your output

Comment: This is maybe (probably) a dumb way to do it, but I'm able to solve this using Mads' unparsed-text selection, but with a tweak:

Comment: Ugh, hit enter too soon...I was also hitting issue with Mads' solution copying everything, but it's a start!.  I got  around it by using substring-before() instead of replace(), and selecting the ']>' that closes the entity declarations.  I'm then dropping in the ']>' with a value-of to close it. That last part is ugly, but I don't know the elegant way to do "substring up to and including".