# Copy !DOCTYPE using xslt

Tags: xslt-3.0

How can `<!DOCTYPE topic PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Topic//EN" "topic.dtd">`

be copied when applying an XSLT transformation?

This is an DTD schema declaration, am I right?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE topic PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Topic//EN" "topic.dtd">
<topic id="utils_documentation_home">
    <title>Documentation</title>
    <body>
        
    </body>
</topic>
```

I tried

```
<xsl:output method="xml" doctype-public="-//OASIS//DTD DITA Topic//EN" doctype-system="topic.dtd"/>
```

XSLT 3.0/4.0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copy Entire Doctype tag from input document using XSLT 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51432291/copy-entire-doctype-tag-from-input-document-using-xslt-2-0) (Yes, it's for 2.0, but the principles still apply.)

Comment: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73695376/367865).

Comment: I saw those examples previously, and now will try them. But I wonder if there in the meantime are more elegant ways to to this.

Comment: The DTD/Doctype is not part of the XSLT/XQuery/XPath data model, so copying it with the means of XSLT/XPath is not possible as you have no access to that information once the XSLT processor is working with its data model. So yes, if you know the input has a certain DTD and want your output to carry that as well, using the necessary `xsl:output` helps. Otherwise you depend on preparsing steps like LexEv provides or used to provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why it did not work at the beginning, but currently this instruction makes the job:

```
 <xsl:output doctype-public="-//OASIS//DTD DITA Topic//EN" doctype-system="topic.dtd" indent="yes" method="xml"/>
```

Though there are some formatting changes, but I think it is not relevant.

[image: Comparison before and after transformation]

Comment: I believe that's creating a new doctype line rather than copying the original one. Whether that matters or not depends on details of your use case.

Comment: Yes, you are right: the way above a new line is created. In my case it was Ok as I know the content before.